# Can I check the battery life of my Apple Magic Keyboard on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

My computer is running Windows 10.  I have an Apple Magic Keyboard hooked up to it.  All seems fine except I have no way of telling how much battery is left in the keyboard minus waiting for it to stop working.

Answer (score 5):

[Bluetooth Battery Monitor](https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/) also can show the battery level of the Magic Keyboard (the model with rechargeable batteries).

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the program. It's paid.

Comment: It is a great tool, for a fair price!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Windows users can monitor the keyboard battery level by using the [Magic Keyboard Utilities](https://www.trackpadmagic.com/magic-keyboard/home) found on this page. Note that this is not Apple software; it is from a third party and it's paid.

I am using it and so far seems okay.